# Moxy. Инъекция презентора в 2 вью

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Всем привет. В фрагменте мне нужно обработать щелчек на кнопку назад. Для этого я добавил интерфейс `IOnBackPressedFragment` и внедрил его в базовый презентер. Архитектуру MVP я еще довольно плохо понимаю, поэтому есть пара вопросов:

1. Как организовать связь активность (отслеживание срабатывания `onBackPressed`) - презентер - фрагмент? До того, как связался с MVP, реализовывал базовый фрагмент и через него обрабатывал `onBackPressed`.
2. Можно ли вообще одним презентором соединить 2 вью?

Answer (score 0):

Так ты же сам написал метод для отслеживания back, там и отслеживай , а насчёт moxy пока туда не лезь. Реализуй паттерн вручную, а потом его уже переведи в moxy, когда ты уже будешь знать принцип работы MVP. Там в принципе ничего сложного нет, реализуешь для презентера и вьюхи свои интерфейсы и через них работаешь.

Насчёт второго вопроса - по конкретней, что ты хочешь?) презентера нужен для того , чтоб в него записывать бизнес логику, данные он подгружает с модели